# How to crop a polygon from an underlying grid with the R sf package?

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I wonder if it is simpler than in the below example with rstats sf, to calculate the (fractional) areal coverage of a polygon shapefile in an underlying grid. So far I haven't found a function, which does that job for me. Here is my example:

```
library(sf)

## create a multipolygon
p1 <- rbind(c(7, 48), c(8, 52), c(11, 49), c(9, 48), c(7, 48))
p2 <- rbind(c(8, 50), c(8, 51), c(9, 50), c(8, 50))
mpol <- st_sfc(st_multipolygon(list(list(p1, p2))), crs=st_crs(4326))

## create a half degree grid covering the multipolygon
grid <- st_make_grid(mpol, cellsize=0.5)

## Create a sf object with the required attributes
## package 'lwgeom' reqiured
area <- st_area(grid)
grid <- st_as_sf(data.frame(ID=c(1:length(area)), area=area, geometry=grid))

## check 'map' elements
plot(grid['area'])
plot(mpol, col="#FF0000AA", add=TRUE)
```

Now comes the calculation, where I first invert the polygon ('ipol') by substracting 'mpol' from the bounding box ('bpol') and calculate the new covered area.

```
## create a rectangular bounding box around the polygon
bbox <- st_bbox(mpol)
bpol <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(rbind(c(bbox['xmin'], bbox['ymin']),
                                     c(bbox['xmax'], bbox['ymin']),
                                     c(bbox['xmax'], bbox['ymax']),
                                     c(bbox['xmin'], bbox['ymax']),
                                     c(bbox['xmin'], bbox['ymin'])))), crs=st_crs(4326))

## invert the multipolygon, by substracting it from the bounding box
ipol <- st_difference(bpol, mpol)

## substract the inverted polygon from the grid
gridinpoly <- st_difference(grid, ipol)

## calculate new 'cropped' area
gridinpoly$croppedArea = st_area(gridinpoly)
plot(gridinpoly['area'])
plot(gridinpoly['croppedArea'])

## Finally the fractional coverage is calculated:
gridinpoly$frac = gridinpoly$croppedArea / gridinpoly$area
plot(gridinpoly['frac'])
```

And it can get even more complicated if a gridcell is covered twice, then cropping the inverted polygon from the grid breaks

```
p3 <- rbind(c(9.75, 50.5), c(10, 51), c(10.5, 50), c(9.75, 50.5))
mpol <- st_sfc(st_multipolygon(list(list(p1, p2, p3))), crs=st_crs(4326))
ipol <- st_difference(bpol, mpol)
gridinpoly <- st_difference(grid, ipol)
```

ERROR message: "Error in CPL_geos_op2(op, st_geometry(x), st_geometry(y)) : Evaluation error: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Nested shells at or near point 9.75 50.5 at 9.75 50.5."

Now my question is, is there already a function, which does that job? Did I miss something in the documentation? And how to solve the error, when a gridcell is cropped several times?

Thanks & kind regards
Jörg

Answer (score 3):

It seems more natural/easy to me to use `st_intersection`.

Reproduce and example almost identical to yours. The only difference is that the crs is not specified. It should work with any crs but not with longitude latitude (see below)

```
library(sf)
## create a multipolygon
p1 <- rbind(c(7, 48), c(8, 52), c(11, 49), c(9, 48), c(7, 48))
p2 <- rbind(c(8, 50), c(8, 51), c(9, 50), c(8, 50))
mpol <- st_sfc(st_multipolygon(list(list(p1, p2))))

## create a half unit grid covering the multipolygon
grid <- st_make_grid(mpol, cellsize=0.5)
area <- st_area(grid)
grid <- st_as_sf(data.frame(ID=c(1:length(area)), area=area, geometry=grid))
```

Compute the fraction of the surface of the grid that is inside the polygon :

```
tmp <- st_intersection(grid, mpol)
tmp$area <- st_area(tmp)
tmp$frac <- tmp$area/unique(area)
plot(tmp['frac'])

# If needed, you can remove the non polygons :
tmp[tmp$area > 0,]
```

This would not work with longitude latitude for a combination of 2 reasons :

1. When `st_area` is used on longitude latitude, `sf` calls another package `geosphere` that works on `sp` objects. Your `sf` object is then transformed on the fly into a `sp` object.
2. In your case the result of the intersection of your grid and polygons is not a multipolygon but a complex object composed of points, lines and polygons (type = Geometry). And the conversion from this type of `sf` object to `sp` does not work

But measuring areas on longitude/latitude is probably not recommended and not needed if you only want a % of surface.

As for your error message with p3, I'm not certain about what you want to simulate. If you want a multipolygon composed of p1 and p3 with hole (p2) in p1, then the syntax to create `mpol` must be slightly different (and the areas computations work correctly) :

```
p3 <- rbind(c(9.75, 50.5), c(10, 51), c(10.5, 50), c(9.75, 50.5))
mpol <- st_sfc(st_multipolygon(list(list(p1, p2), list(p3))))
plot(mpol)

tmp <- st_intersection(grid, mpol)
tmp$area <- st_area(tmp)
tmp$frac <- tmp$area/unique(area)
plot(tmp['frac'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm so stupid, you are totally right. When I tried `st_intersection` I used gridpoints instead of the grid polygons and got TRUE/FALSE only. I will do it with the real data now.